# Get the Biggest (int) Input From a Loop and Print it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how to get the biggest 'int(input) from the user in a loop.  For example:

```
def main():
    times = int(input('How many times will you do this: ')
    for i in range(times):
        num = int(input('Enter a number: ')
main()
```

I want to know how I could get the biggest number from the user's input from something like this and print it.

If I said I wanted to enter a number 5 times and entered 6, 1, 21, 34, 3.  I would want it to print 34 because that is the biggest value entered by the user.

This is just an example!

Comment: Keep track of the numbers the users enters, after the loop, pick the highest one

Comment: How would I do that? @TimCastelijns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the numbers the users enters, after the loop, pick the highest one using the `max` function.

```
def main():
    numbers = []
    times = int(input('How many times will you do this: '))
    for i in range(times):
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        numbers.append(num)
    print(str(max(numbers)) + ' is the biggest number.')
main()
```

Comment: I also want to make it so it doesn't give the number is the biggest value..  It's going to be hard to explain with the example I gave.  So, now I want the output to be the number, but when it was given in the loop.  For example, if the user entered 1, 9, 5, I'd like to know how to make it print something like 9 is the biggest number.  Thanks in advanced! @TimCastelijns

Comment: No, but it's okay.  I don't think it could be answered with the example I've chosen.  No worries. @TimCastelijns

Comment: @MaxOwnz does this answer the question then?

Comment: Yes, it helped get further! @TimCastelijns

Comment: Ok, don't hesitate to come back to SO if you get stuck